# Prevent Android wrapper to website

Tags: android, http

Our website is mobile ready and provides service to end uses. Someone has developed a wrapper application around the website and published on playstore. I checked the web request header from this wrapper application and from mobile browser and they are identical.

Is there any other way to differentiate if the request is from webview of native application or mobile browser?

Comment: I guess you could contact Google about this issue if it is in violation to your terms. I'm not sure but I think I've heard about apps being pulled by Google when related issues have been reported to paid apps.

Comment: @Kulai Did you find a solution to that problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately for your case, a WebView is indistinguishable from the default mobile browser. So I believe that you have a legal problem here, not a technical one.

As @Daniel says, you may want to appeal to Google to have the app removed from the Play Store.

Since there seems to be some market out there for a native version, perhaps you should look at providing your own. If you provide some extra added value in a native app, there would be less incentive for someone else to wrap your web app.

Comment: There is already a native app and it is better to publish it in the mobile web page

Answer (score 0):

you can according to User-Agent， of course, you can custom User-Agent

Comment: But how difficult is it to imitate the custom user agent? I can have a Map containing header name and value and inject it when opening the URL in web view.

Comment: Since standard mobile browsers should be allowed for the mobile site, the user agent can't be verified. So customized values in user agent can't be verified.